# Found a film or strip stuck inside the back cover of Lenovo K3 Note

Tags: lenovo

I have a a phone Lenovo K3 Note. I noticed something paper like stuck on the back cover of the phone. It is like a film, found on clothes of some stores so that no one can steal them. But what its use on my phone, I couldn't understand. These are the images of the sticker:

Stuck on the cover
[image: Image of film]
[image: Image Of Film]

Upper side
[image: Upper side of film]

Was stuck like this
[image: Was stuck like this]

Do anyone know why it is put there, I am little suspicious about it.

Comment: Just a regular graphite sticker to help with radiation (the grainy texture and easily-crumpled nature hints at it) - this is getting typical nowadays. If you're not sure you could always cut the sticker apart and check if there are any wiring in it - if it's used for any other purpose it will have a circuit inside. Also, I'm voting this as Android-independent since it's not about the OS, but about a phone using the OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be just a sticker to counter radiation, as @Andy Yan said. I tore off the the sticker there was just some black slippery substance coated. There was nothing like the stickers on clothes bought from few stores. (So its not the RFID sticker @davidgo)
But, I browsed about such type of stickers, 'Anti Radiation Sticker' there were no supporting blogs or comments about its use found, other than on the sites selling them. Then why the company itself using them? I couldn't understand.

[Visit the link, advocating uselessness of Anti Radiation Stickers](https://sensology.wordpress.com/2013/11/14/mobile-phone-anti-radiation-chip-critical-analysis/)

Edit - Its not a 'Anti Radiation Sticker', it absorbs dissipating heat, made from graphite while ARS are made of metal.
(Thanks to @AndyYan)

Comment: By "radiation" I mean dissipating heat, hence the graphite material. "Anti-radiation" stickers on the market, on the other hand, are usually made out of metal.

Comment: Oh! I understood it it. Now I will stick it again. Thankyou @AndyYan, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to people at https://www.reddit.com/r/lenovok3note/comments/3eousk/could_the_lenovo_k3_note_be_optimised_for/ it's used for shielding the Sim cards.

I'd be surprised, and posit it is actually an anti-theft or tracking RFID sticker - possibly bigger then typical as it needs to work through more packaging?